# Is it unsafe to use query strings in the url?

Tags: php, html, security

Our PM has ordered us to implement security for a site we've been working on.

To display product details, I make use of query strings.

My URL looks like `www.domain.com?index.php&product id=1&product-type-id=4`

My colleague argued that this is unsafe, and that we should hide that information from the URL. They suggested that we use a session instead.

In my opinion, nothing is unsafe about the use of query strings as long as I do server side validation, pass the active user id to my query to make sure people can only access their products.

What vulnerabilities could a URL like this cause:

`www.domain.com?index.php&product id=1&product-type-id=4`

Comment: As long as the id's are used in a prepared statement or otherwise escaped in PHP AND the id's passed are checked for authorization (if required) it is totally fine.  There is no benefit to "hiding" this information as it will always be accessible to the end user and security through obscurity is ridiculous.

Comment: This is literally the purpose of GET variables.

Comment: Shouldn't the url be formatted like `www.domain.com/index.php?product id=1&product-type-id=4`? The format could be correct as listed above, though I've never seen a URL formatted like that

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton that is exactly what I thought, the php $_GET method wouldn't exist if urls like this one were not allowed...the rule of thumb is to always sanitize information b4 its passed to a query

Comment: @DavidChopin yes It should look like that...I forgot the /

Comment: Thanks for your comments everybody

Comment: Also, `?` denotes the beginning of the query string while `&` is the separator for each parameter and its corresponding value. https://sitechecker.pro/what-is-url/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deciding between `$_POST` and `$_GET` ask yourself this: Is there any reason the user shouldn't be able to see this? Using `$_GET` also allows the user to bookmark or share the url, so for a product page like this I would 100% recommend  continue to use it in this way. `$_GET` is not inherently unsafe as long as you are sanitizing anything you receive from it. They both exist for a reason and have their uses.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Laif , this is a private page, they wouldn't necessarily  want to share it....I thought post was for submitting data to the server ? and in this case we're trying to get product details..

Comment: They're both for sending data to the server, $_GET just appends it to the url instead of sending via session. You are using $_GET in this example. If the page is private why is your coworker even worried about security? Furthermore, keep in mind that if someone was trying to attack you, they could just as easily send unsanitized $_POST data via a client like postman. Just sanitize everything given to you and you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks a lot . .

Comment: And correct me if Im wrong, $_POST is usually used when a user submits an html form. In this scenario, I have list of products I pass the product id and type to the url when a user clicks on a product to view it. $_POST is not applicable in this scenario, right ?

Comment: It’s possible to use either, they are means to the same end. For a user-end product page I would most definitely use $_GET

Comment: How would I use $_POST in this scenario ?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you could do it but it would be rather hacky. You are correct.

Comment: OK, thanks for taking your time and reply to my questions.#much appreciated.

Comment: If this answer answered your question consider marking it as such

Comment: Done ! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The security problem isn't tied to the query string.  The difference between get and post are just at the protocol level and either can be forged.

The security issue comes up when you don't properly validate variables and escape them as needed.

Never trust user input. Always validate it.

Comment: Thanks your comment chase